# Is there a way to enable VSCode intellisense for a node .mjs project?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, mjs

I'm writing a small node `cli` app in a sub-folder of my project.

I'm using `.mjs` files.

Is there a way to enable VSCode intellisense?

I tried with a `.jsconfig` with no luck.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible due to the fact that modules are rejected as a standard by vscode and microsoft.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).